# Cannot reference a dll in console application but I can in wpf

Tags: c#, dll, skype4com

- I have a console application and a wpf application.
- on both applications I have added the skype4com.dll reference
- The code: `SKYPE4COMLib.Skype oSkype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();`

gives an: `InvalidCastExeption` stating:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'SKYPE4COMLib.Skype'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B1878BFE-53D3-402E-8C86-190B19AF70D5}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

but when I run the same line of code in my wpf application I don't get an exception. why!?

---

My console application was running great until skype updated. I uninstalled skype, installed it again in order to try to solve the problem but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours of trying I decided I where going to make my wpf application a console application by adding the necessary references and classes. Then I compared and I noticed that if I added:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
```

to the main method it works!!!!!

as a result my main method now should look like:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    class Program
    {
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]                
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SKYPE4COMLib.Skype oSkype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
        }
    }
}
```

on asp.net there is not a main method. well not one that I know of. so in asp.net I had to add the AspCompat attribute equal to true.

so my asp.net aspx pages now look like:

```
    <%@ Page AspCompat="true" Language="C#" .... etc
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use the client profile for you Console app, set it to the full .Net version.

You change it by going into the project properties -> Application -> Target Framework (Drop Down) -> Set it to .Net Framework 4 (If it's that version of .net you are running)

Comment: That fix it for my console application but it did not for my .asp application. I thought that if it was going to work in my console application it was going to work in my asp application. 1 hour ago it was working nice until skype updated.